# What is the average and worst case time complexity of this algorithm I wrote?

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

This is my answer to a test question meant to find a subarray in an array that answers a certain criteria, I won't bore you with the details. I lost most points for this answer because the complexity is supposedly O(n^2), where the answer should be O(n). However, I'm not certain they are correct in their statement of the complexity of my answer. Could any of you give me further feedback?

```
public static void findSubarray (int[] arr, int target){
   boolean found = false;
   for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
   {
       int sum = 0;
       for (int k=i; k<= arr.length; k++)
       {
           if (arr[k] == target)
           {
               found = true;
               break;
                       }
               sum = sum + arr[k];
           if (sum == target)
           {
               found = true;
               break;
                       }
           if (sum>target)
               break;
               }
       if (found == true)
           break;
       }
```

I argue that because the inner loop doesn't necessarily iterate over the entire array every time it's called, the worst-case scenario *may* be O(n^2), but the average-case scenario might be O(n), right?

Comment: Why is this question marked with the [tag:java] tag? Posted code is NOT valid Java code! (missing any blocks aka `{}`; missing semi-colon; unreachable code; `break` outside loop or `switch`; ...)

Comment: Your algorithm is O(n), as only `int sum = 0` is in the first loop.

Comment: This code is still broken. Neither of your loops have a closing `}`

Comment: You could probably spend your time better learning to make this an O(n) algorithm, then waiting for somebody to reduce the n of your poor algorithm. The least you could do is say why it should be 'n' instead of n^2 instead of hoping somebody proves it for you. "but the average-case scenario might be O(n), right?" no, but why do you think it is and maybe somebody will dispell you.

Answer (score 3):

On average, the inner loop iterates over *half* of the array, ie O(n/2). But when describing time complexity, we discard linear multipliers (in this case 1/2), so the time complexity of the inner loop is O(n), making the overall complexity O(n^2).

The non-mathy way to express this is to observe that if n doubles then n/2 doubles, so there's a constant ratio of the complexity of the inner loop with n, so O(n).

---

By the way, as a hint to the O(n) solution, being O(n) doesn't mean you only iterate over the array once; it just means you iterate over it a *constant* number of times. Think about what you can learn about the array by iterating over the whole array first and what information you can store about every location in the array.